# TypeError: products.find is not a function node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I have an data file products.js in node js.
I want to fetch json data by id (/api/products/:id) from this js file. But its show e TypeError: products.find is not a function node js.
My Data file:
**Products.js**

```
exports.products = [
  {
    _id: '1',
    name: 'Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones',
    image: '/images/airpods.jpg',
    description:
      'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 89.99,
    countInStock: 10,
    rating: 4.5,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '2',
    name: 'iPhone 11 Pro 256GB Memory',
    image: '/images/phone.jpg',
    description:
      'Introducing the iPhone 11 Pro. A transformative triple-camera system that adds tons of capability without complexity. An unprecedented leap in battery life',
    brand: 'Apple',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 599.99,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 4.0,
    numReviews: 8,
  },
  {
    _id: '3',
    name: 'Cannon EOS 80D DSLR Camera',
    image: '/images/camera.jpg',
    description:
      'Characterized by versatile imaging specs, the Canon EOS 80D further clarifies itself using a pair of robust focusing systems and an intuitive design',
    brand: 'Cannon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 929.99,
    countInStock: 5,
    rating: 3,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '4',
    name: 'Sony Playstation 4 Pro White Version',
    image: '/images/playstation.jpg',
    description:
      'The ultimate home entertainment center starts with PlayStation. Whether you are into gaming, HD movies, television, music',
    brand: 'Sony',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 399.99,
    countInStock: 11,
    rating: 5,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
  {
    _id: '5',
    name: 'Logitech G-Series Gaming Mouse',
    image: '/images/mouse.jpg',
    description:
      'Get a better handle on your games with this Logitech LIGHTSYNC gaming mouse. The six programmable buttons allow customization for a smooth playing experience',
    brand: 'Logitech',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 49.99,
    countInStock: 7,
    rating: 3.5,
    numReviews: 10,
  },
  {
    _id: '6',
    name: 'Amazon Echo Dot 3rd Generation',
    image: '/images/alexa.jpg',
    description:
      'Meet Echo Dot - Our most popular smart speaker with a fabric design. It is our most compact smart speaker that fits perfectly into small space',
    brand: 'Amazon',
    category: 'Electronics',
    price: 29.99,
    countInStock: 0,
    rating: 4,
    numReviews: 12,
  },
]
```

Then I import this products file in my server js.
**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const products = require('./data/products');

const app = express();

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    res.send('API is running......')
    })
app.get('/api/products',(req,res) => {
    res.json(products)
    })
app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
    const product = products.find((p) => p._id === req.params.id)
    res.json(product)

})
app.listen(5000, console.log('server running on port 5000'));
```

My file structure-->
Backend(Rootfolder[image])

Data->products.js
server.js

Comment: It is due to strict comparison === make it == it will work else in products array make it _id as integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you export your data with `exports.products` so if you want to get that array, you need to change your code to `const { products } = require('./data/products')`